# python EOF when reading a line, only happens when i terminate

Tags: python

My code is working fine, except that when i terminate it during running, EOF sometimes happens. The thing that weried is:
The first time i start it, then i terminate it, EOF happens.
But the second time for the same procedure, it does not happen. I do not know why.
The following is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\newworkspace\SlicePython\SliceManage.py", line 303, in <module>
    Mainloop()
  File "D:\newworkspace\SlicePython\SliceManage.py", line 13, in Mainloop
    updaterecord()
  File "D:\newworkspace\SlicePython\SliceManage.py", line 105, in updaterecord
    db_name = input()
  File "D:\eclipse\eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.6.0.201406232321\pysrc\pydev_sitecustomize\sitecustomize.py", line 161, in input
    ret = original_input(prompt)
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

My code is always using the while loop to get input,like:

```
while(True):#have to check if this database exists
    db_name = input()
    db = env.openDB(db_name)
    if(db==None):
        print("database does not exist ,please input again!")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Note this never happens when it is running.

Comment: How do you start it and how do you terminate it?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? By what method are you terminating the program?

Comment: It is python 3 , i am using eclipse so i terminate it with "terminate" button.